# Mono for Android can not create assembly directory

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create programs for Android in C#. When I start an emulator and I click the debug button, the output says:

```
Deployment failed. The assembly directory could not be created.
```

Have I to have a permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`, that allows me to create directories and files?

Thanks for answers :).

Comment: Have you tried opening MonoDevelop as an administrator (or super user depending on OS?)

Comment: Not working - same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a same problem too.

Try This:
In Project Properties > Build > Change the platform target into x86.

Then Rebuild again.

hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

in project option -> build -> mono for android build

check mark on 'use shared mono runtime'

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to create a directory in your code, or is this referring to the compiler's assembly directory? You only need a permission in the manifest if you are creating directories and files on the android device (i.e. in your code). You should not need this permission for a simple deployment.

Sometimes it's the simple things: make sure you have enough disk space, and that the full file path is not too long.

If none of that works, it may be an emulator problem; try it on a physical device to make sure.